# Apache NiFi can not connect to "localhost:8080/nifi"

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to run Apache NiFi on my CentOS system. I downloaded it and run it with command:

```
/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/bin/nifi.sh start
```

the result is here:

```
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45
NiFi home: /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/conf/bootstrap.conf

2016-03-06 22:02:08,477 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2016-03-06 22:02:08,478 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12
2016-03-06 22:02:08,478 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -classpath /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./conf:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/nifi-runtime-1.1.1.0-12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/nifi-nar-utils-1.1.1.0-12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/nifi-properties-1.1.1.0-12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/logback-core-1.1.3.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/nifi-documentation-1.1.1.0-12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/nifi-api-1.1.1.0-12.jar:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Dnifi.properties.file.path=/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/./conf/nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=32864 -Dapp=NiFi org.apache.nifi.NiFi
```

then I check the status of Apache NiFi with command:

```
/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/bin/nifi.sh status
```

and the result was:

```
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45
NiFi home: /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/conf/bootstrap.conf

2016-03-06 22:03:21,227 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 45542, PID=30817
```

but at the end when I try to access to http://localhost:8090/nifi or http://localhost:8080/nifi on my browser it said : unable to connect. (I changed the http port to 8090 to avoid conflicts, but still have the same problem). Please help me, what is the problem?

Here is `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log`:

```
2016-03-07 00:31:54,204 ERROR [Cleanup Archive for default] o.a.n.c.repository.FileSystemRepository Failed to cleanup archive for container default due to java.io.IOException: Mount point not found
2016-03-07 00:31:54,216 INFO [main] o.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController Controller has been terminated successfully.
2016-03-07 00:31:54,225 WARN [main] org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@d2b452{/nifi-api,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,STARTING}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.1.1.0-12.war}
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) [jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:663) [nifi-jetty-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:137) [nifi-runtime-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:227) [nifi-runtime-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./flowfile_repository/partition-119/2.journal: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:380) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:106) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.createDataInputStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:932) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getRecoveryStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:947) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getNextRecoverableTransactionId(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:973) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromEdits(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:419) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:293) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.loadFlowFiles(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:328) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.initializeFlow(FlowController.java:573) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:622) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:458) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:79) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
2016-03-07 00:31:54,427 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@ec15ce{/nifi-content-viewer,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,429 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@917ef5{/nifi-docs,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,457 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@260a31{/nifi-docs,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,483 INFO [main] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@15dcce1{/,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,497 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector Started ServerConnector@1e4a851{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8089}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,497 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @27531ms
2016-03-07 00:31:54,499 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller.
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:99) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:800) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354) ~[jetty-server-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar:9.2.11.v20150529]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:663) ~[nifi-jetty-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:137) [nifi-runtime-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:227) [nifi-runtime-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./flowfile_repository/partition-119/2.journal: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:315) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:380) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:106) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.createDataInputStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:932) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getRecoveryStream(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:947) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog$Partition.getNextRecoverableTransactionId(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:973) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverFromEdits(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:419) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.recoverRecords(MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog.java:293) ~[nifi-write-ahead-log-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.loadFlowFiles(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:328) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController.initializeFlow(FlowController.java:573) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.loadFromBytes(StandardFlowService.java:622) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService.load(StandardFlowService.java:458) ~[nifi-framework-core-1.1.1.0-12.jar:1.1.1.0-12]
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:79) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
2016-03-07 00:31:54,500 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2016-03-07 00:31:54,503 INFO [Thread-1] org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector Stopped ServerConnector@1e4a851{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8089}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,511 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@15dcce1{/,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-error-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-error-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,513 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@260a31{/nifi-docs,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-docs-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-docs-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,515 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@917ef5{/nifi-docs,null,UNAVAILABLE}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,516 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@ec15ce{/nifi-content-viewer,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,518 INFO [Thread-1] o.a.n.w.c.ApplicationStartupContextListener Initiating shutdown of flow service...
2016-03-07 00:31:54,518 INFO [Thread-1] o.a.n.w.c.ApplicationStartupContextListener Flow service termination completed.
2016-03-07 00:31:54,518 INFO [Thread-1] /nifi-api Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-03-07 00:31:54,643 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@d2b452{/nifi-api,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-api-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-api-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,656 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@13f7ede{/nifi,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-web-ui-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/framework/nifi-framework-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-web-ui-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,682 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2b0fea{/nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.1.1.0-12,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-update-attribute-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-update-attribute-ui-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,699 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1680713{/nifi-image-viewer-1.1.1.0-12,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-image-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-image-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-image-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,704 INFO [Thread-1] o.e.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@155d5e4{/nifi-standard-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12,file:/opt/nifi-1.1.1.0-12/work/jetty/nifi-standard-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.1.1.0-12.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/nifi-standard-content-viewer-1.1.1.0-12.war}
2016-03-07 00:31:54,714 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

Comment: I am getting this error in apache nifi logs: [NiFi logging handler] org.apache.nifi.StdErr 
Failed to start web server: Unable to start Flow Controller.

Comment: Can you provide some of the information from the nifi-app.log within the logs directory as well?

Comment: Thank a lot. I add some lines of nifi-app.log at the end of my question.

Answer (score 10):

I see the error : "Too many open files"

I would suggest to increase this limit as recommended in https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem resolved. I increased the limits and finally it work.